# Is try catch the only way to catch PDO errors when checking if a sql did its job?

Tags: php, pdo

Is try catch the only way to catch PDO errors to check if a sql performed? Early on, I used to do like below. I don't need the error message, error names etc. Just a true or false. If the sql worked or not. Can this be done in some other way other than using try catch.

**Before**

```
$createUser = (insert into table (someCol) values (someVal));

$exeCreateUser = mysql_query($createUser);

if($exeCreateUser)
{ //The SQL query worked well
  echo 'All went on well';
}else{
 //The SQL query failed!
  echo 'Failed';
}
```

**Now**

```
$sql  = 'insert into names (names) values (:what)';
$what = "This value";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindParam(':what', $what, PDO::PARAM_STR, 5);
$stmt->execute();
```

Can I do something like I used to do before, instead of using try catch?

Comment: PDOs `->execute()` call also returns a boolean result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php

### Return Values

> Returns TRUE on success or FALSE on failure.

Comment: So in my case, whats the right way to do it? I seem to be getting True even when It should be false...

Comment: With properly set ERRMODE_EXCEPTION script execution will never reach this condition.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`PDO::setAttribute`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.setattribute.php) to set `PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE` to a value other than `PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION` before calling methods.

If you do this, you need to then check for errors using either [`PDO::errorCode`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.errorcode.php) or [`PDOStatement::errorCode`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.errorcode.php), *whatever is appropriate for each operation*.

> `PDO::errorCode()` only retrieves error codes for operations performed
>   directly on the database handle. If you create a `PDOStatement` object
>   through `PDO::prepare()` or `PDO::query()` and invoke an error on the
>   statement handle, `PDO::errorCode()` will not reflect that error. You
>   must call `PDOStatement::errorCode()` to return the error code for an
>   operation performed on a particular statement handle.

Comment: To set PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE to a value other than PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION

Comment: @YourCommonSense: Irrespective of that, it is exactly what the OP asked for **and** they gave a very compelling reason: they want to move off `mysql`, but cannot rewrite their app from scratch. *That* would be the wrong idea. In any case I neither care nor expect to convince you. Just for posterity.

Answer (score -1):

**You don't need neither try..catch nor anything else.**

In general, you don't need to check if your query were successful or not. On a properly tuned system all queries run smoothly.

But if some query gone wild - it means something went wrong and whole appication have to be halted. So - there is no use for checking every separate query - you just have to catch a thrown exception at application level.

So, there is no use for such a condition at all. A failure on insert doesn't mean failure with CreateUser, but site-wide failure. And you don't need no local check, but just site-wide exception handler and a generic error 503 page